# Grab Data From Remote page HTML <a> tag

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

Hi there I have a little problem that i need fixed as soon as possible.

I am the owner of an addon for the xbmc/kodi platform i have coded a php back end to help me find and add content but i am having a problem getting data from one of the sites i use

On the site there is a link from this link i need to get the href and some text from the title attribute

I can grab all the links on the page and go threw them and get the link i want i can then get the herf attribute but the problem i have is getting the title attribute and getting just the text i need from it

the html code for the link is below

```
    <a title="Stream AMC- waliing dead Episode 12 No Ads and easy on - EasyPlayer" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="example.com/watch.php?id=64">EasyPlayer!</a>
```

from this link i can grab the href but not the title or the text i need from it

the only text i need is ( AMC- Walking dead ) this is dynamic and will change for every page i load

can someone help please i will post the code i have so far below

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $url = $_POST['url'];
   $fanart = "http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/1/736215-anime-wallpaper.jpg";
   $anime_thumbnail = "http://www.apkdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Anime-Wallpapers-HD-Icon.png";
   $plot = "Anime System by MetaBox HD IPTV";

   $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");

  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  @$dom->loadHTML($input);

  foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {

  if(strpos($node->getAttribute('title'),'- EasyMode') !== false) {

  $expires = preg_split('/Episode|episode/',$node->getAttribute('title'));
   array_shift($expires);

  $stream_url = $node->getAttribute('href');
  $title_edit = str_replace(" Anime Series", "", $node->getAttribute('title'));
   $title = str_replace("Watch ", "", $title_edit);

   }
   print_r($expires);
  }
 }
```

i need the out put of $anime_url to be the herf attribute

and i need the output of $title to be the text i need from the title attribute

thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: I would suggest starting all anchors with either http:// or https:// to avoid any issue's. Not all devices understand a url without a indicated protocol.

Comment: How do you know what part of the title you need? If you can define a pattern, it might be easier to compile some regex for this. Which parts appear always, and which ones are dynamic?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments i got it done my self after some work :)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem my self

by looking at the title of the videos streams i was grabbing even tho dynamic i noticed there was one of two words that would all ways appear

No and |episode

i then simply used a explode function to split the string at eather word and then used replace function to remove the remaining word (stream)

and the ran the full thing threw a saftey function to remove all html tags and special chars

and it works perfect now :)